# GridBagLayout multiple buttons + border

Tags: swing, border, gridbaglayout, java

I'm trying to use `GridBagLayout` for 10 (3x3 + 1) `JButtons` inside a `JPanel` using `BoxLayout`.

But what ever I do with glueboxes or similarly the `GridBagLayout` `JPanel` takes up all the extra space in the `BoxLayout`. I'm probably missing something or is this not possible to do?

One solution I have used is to push the buttons up with a expanding element inside the gridbaglayout. This puts the buttons in the right place but the border box appear to big.

Here follows my example code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagLayoutTest extends JFrame {

    public GridBagLayoutTest(){
        super();
        this.setTitle("JVectorView");
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = this.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        content.add(new JLabel("Hello!"));
        content.add(new Controls());
        content.add(Box.createGlue());
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    private class Controls extends JPanel{
        private static final int WIDTH = 3, HEIGHT = 3;

        public Controls(){
            GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

            //this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Some stuff"));
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++){
                for(int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++){
                    constraints.gridx = col;
                    constraints.gridy = row;
                    this.add(new JButton("B"+(col+row*WIDTH)), constraints);

                }
            }
            constraints.gridx = 1;
            constraints.gridy = 3;
            this.add(new JButton("B"+(10)), constraints);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayoutTest();
    }

}
```

I would like the border to be tight around the buttons. Is it at all possible to get gridbaglayout to collapse in on it's content or does it always force fill the panels?

Comment: Maybe try tweaking the min and max size of the components you're putting in the grid?

Comment: are you want to fill available `JPanel's` area with 10 `JButtons` ???

Comment: +1 for a compilable, simple explanation of your problem

Comment: mKorbel I want the JPanel with the buttons to not be bigger then the sum of the button sizes (+borders and stuff). (Edit pressed enter by mistake) Especially in the vertical where I think the glue element should take the rest of the space.

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel p=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
p.add(new Controls());
content.add(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem with flowLayout is that I can't control what direction I want the components in. In this case I want them to go vertical.